# Hook SetWindowLongW API

Tags: c++, api, hook

This is how i init the hook

```
if (MH_CreateHookApiEx(L"user32", "SetWindowLongW", &MySetWindowLongW, (LPVOID*)&oSetWindowLongW, nullptr) != MH_OK)
    {
        std::cout << "MHook Fail To Install Hook." << std::endl;
        goto exit;
    }
    if (MH_EnableHook(&SetWindowLongW) != MH_OK)
    {
        std::cout << "MHook Fail To Enable Hook." << std::endl;
        goto exit;
    }
```

```
typedef LONG(WINAPI* _MySetWindowLongW)(HWND, int, LONG);
_MySetWindowLongW oSetWindowLongW = nullptr;

LONG MySetWindowLongW(
    HWND hWnd,
    int  nIndex,
    LONG dwNewLong
)
{
    return oSetWindowLongW(hWnd, nIndex, dwNewLong);
}
```

The Hook work, BUT the problem is after first exec to `MySetWindowLongW`
in Visual Studio i get `has triggered a breakpoint.` after function finish.

I think it's Stack or it's Call Conversation. i really don't know.

But i tried with `CreateWindowExW` it's work normal.
The problem with `SetWindowLongW` only.

Comment: i get `has triggered a breakpoint.` in Visual Studio.

Comment: it's after exit the function in debugger, what u think the problem is .?

Comment: I don't know. I think more code context is needed. I asked the first question because you mentioned a problem but did not explain what the problem was.

Comment: i think it's Stack problem, cased by Wrong prams or it's fastcall. **Can u test the hook**.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not familiar with MinHook, but I get what it does.  Here's a couple of shot in the dark guesses:

Pass `MySetWindowLongW` as the Detour function to MH_CreateHookEx instead of `&MySetWindowLongW`. That may or may not make a difference.  That is:

```
if (MH_CreateHookApiEx(L"user32", "SetWindowLongW", MySetWindowLongW, (LPVOID*)&oSetWindowLongW, nullptr) != MH_OK)
```

Declare and define your hook function as stdcall to be consistent with the calling convention of the function your are hooking

```
extern "C" LONG WINAPI MySetWindowLongW(
    HWND hWnd,
    int  nIndex,
    LONG dwNewLong) {...}
```

Comment: ty, i figure the problem was i forget `WINAPI` in Function Declare `LONG WINAPI MySetWindowLongW(HWND hWnd, int  nIndex, LONG dwNewLong)`, it's works now. (no need for `extern "C" `)

Comment: for anyone will visit this answer `MH_CreateHookEx` is good in the question it's all about `WINAPI` (__stdcall), and thanks to @selbie